# Good resources to start learning Reverse Engineering

Tags: career-advice

Can you please suggest me good starting learning resources for Reverse Engineering. I am a complete newbie to reverse engineering but have good programming experience. I have experience in programming on Linux/C++ & Java.

I would appreciate an example based approach as it becomes boring to learn tons of theory without getting a chance to apply it.

Thanks.

Comment: While more focused on Windows, I think the book "Practical Malware Analysis" is a great introduction to the topic. Includes labs for every chapter. http://www.amazon.com/Practical-Malware-Analysis-Dissecting-Malicious/dp/1593272901

Answer (score 6):

I recommend http://beginners.re/ . The book  is good, has plenty of examples and exercises.